# Custom TestRunner for nunit

Tags: c#, nunit, test-runner

Having following test flow:

```
foreach(tc in testcases)
    foreach(temperature in temperatures)
    {
        SetTemperature(temperature);
        foreach(position in positions)
        {
            Robot.GotoPosition(position);
            DoTest(tc);
        }
    }
```

This tests an external component on various temperatures and on various positions.

Is it possible to write an custom `runner` for `nunit`to archieve such a behavior?

Comment: Just use TestCaseSource and a normal runner?

Comment: You mean create parametrized testcase? So this multiplies up to `temperatures`*`positions`*`testcases` single testcases? For my situation: When selecting `TestcaseA` and `26°` the robot drives to all position and does the testcase. If all positions pass the test case is a pass. I don't want to put the robot into the testcase itself since all testcases have to do this.

Comment: You can use `TestCaseSource` to yield all the test cases - you don't need to specify a separate attribute for each combination.